# zip argument #1 must support iteration

Tags: python-2.7

I want to do simple lists multiplication. It works good for c but fails for d with following error: TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Any suggestion to correct it would be appreciative.

```
    x=[]
    area1 = (area1)/100
    area2 = (area2)/100
    area3 = (area3)/100
    x.append(area1)
    x.append(area2)
    x.append(area3)
    # resultant x is [0.96, 0.03, 0.0]

    a = [13.87, 14.78, 10.3]
    b = [0.44, 0.39, 0.38]

    c = sum([x* a for x, a in zip(x, a)])
    d = sum([x* b for x, b in zip(x, b)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use names other than x, a and b in your list comprehensions:

```
c = sum([_x * _a for _x, _a in zip(x, a)])
d = sum([_x * _b for _x, _b in zip(x, b)])
```

Yours is re-assigning x to be the first element of x and failing on the second usage of `zip` with x.

You can instead use `map` and `operator.mul`:

```
from operator import mul
c = sum(map(mul, x, a))
d = sum(map(mul, x, b))
```

Comment: I just tried OP's post and I don't understand either why his code doesn't work as it looks like it should. What is the `_` prefix doing, can you explain your answer a bit more?

Comment: It works when using simple lists in the IDLE window but fails within script. Your suggestion worked. I still don't understand what "_" prefix doing?

Comment: It is just a different name. Any names other than x, a and b would work.